# The best way to store date in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

I need to store resource creation date in arangodb. Furthermore, I need to filter resources by creation date:

```
FOR doc in Docs
    FILTER doc.created < @some_date
    RETURN doc
```

What is the best way to do that?

---

Possible solutions:

```json
{
    // one
    created: "<iso8601-date>", // Persistent index, use DATE_TIMESTAMP()

    // two
    created: "<timestamp-str>", // Persistent index, use TO_NUMBER
    
    // three
    created: <timestamp-int>, // Persistent index
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found this [documentation](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-date.html#working-with-dates-and-indices). In brief: date can be stored as string in iso8601 format either as a numeric timestamp. All compare operations will work correctly and efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you store dates in the Unix Epoch Seconds format, as this helps with date range queries and ensures your clients can reliably format the date to a usable format.

When the date is just a number, then it's very easy to do time queries over ranges as 1 hour is just 3600 seconds.

If you need more granularity, then storing dates as Unix Epoch MilliSeconds also helps.

You can store dates earlier than 1/1/1970 with this format, they will just be negative integers.